# Bash script to open multiple terminal widows?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to open multiple terminal windows (20 to be specific) through a bash script. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 20`;
  do
  gnome-terminal
done
```

Comment: You need `&` at the end of `gnome-terminal` command, otherwise the script will run sequentially, opening one window at a time

Comment: What if I want to do the same thing for mac terminal ?

Answer (score 4):

This little script should be helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..19}
do
    xterm &
done
```

Explanation:

1. `{0..19}`: number range from 0 to 19 to give total of twenty
2. `xterm &`: opens terminal and allows you to *detach* from the original terminal

Comment: Yes it's automatic..

Answer (score 3):

Try gnu parallel:

```
parallel -j20 gnome-terminal ::: {1..20}
```